# Can a function $f(g(x))$ where $g(x)=c_1$ be considered strictly increasing (decreasing)?

Tags: analysis, functions

Let's say I have a function, $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x)=c_1$ and $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have another function, $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f(g(x))=c_2$ and $c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

My question: is $f$ considered (vacuously) strictly increasing? It seems like it would obviously be "no" since $f$ is a constant. However, since the definition of strictly increasing is "if $x_1 > x_2$, then $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$," $x_1 > x_2$ can never be true as $f$ doesn't vary over the set of values that $g$ takes on and is therefore vacuously true.

Do we care about the values that $g$ takes on (that is, only $c_1$), or do we only care about the values of $x?$ I guess the importance of this point could also change the domain of $f$ to $f: \{c_1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I know this seems like a very technical and trivial point, but it actually is relevant to something that I am doing.

Comment: `f:R→R defined as f(g(x))=c_2` This does not define a real function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,$, it merely defines the value $f(c_1)\,$. Whether the function $f$ is monotonic or not (strictly or not) on $\mathbb{R}$ depends on how $f$ is defined on the rest of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{c_1\}\,$.

Comment: Thanks. This actually helped get to the heart of my problem. I was only checking $f$ for values that $g$ could take on, not over all possible input values for $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dxiv points out, you have not defined f on $\mathbb{R}$ yet.  So, whether f is increasing or not is not yet answerable.  You have however, defined $f\circ g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that is a constant function, certainly not strictly increasing since you can check it for $x_2 > x_1$

Comment: Thanks, this answer (along with dxiv's comment) helped me figure out why I was confused.